# Low energy limit in scattering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, scattering

Suppose I have a quantum system described by $H = -\Delta + V(r)$, where $\Delta$ is the usual Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $V$ is a nonnegative radial potential which decays fast enough. In scattering theory, one wants to solve the Schrödinger equation:
$$H \psi = E\psi = \frac{1}{2}p^{2}\psi.$$
The solution of this problem is well-known. One uses spherical coordinates ${\bf{r}} = (r,\theta,\varphi)$ and assumes that for $r$ sufficiently large it is of the form:
$$\psi(r,\theta,\phi) = e^{i pz} + f(p,\theta)\frac{e^{i|p| r}}{r}.$$
Let me focus on the $f$ function. We can expand it as:
$$f(p,\theta) = \frac{1}{|p|}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(2l+1)e^{i\delta_{l}}\sin\delta_{l}P_{l}(\cos\theta),$$
where $\delta_{l}$ is a parameter related to the phase shift.

Here's my question. As far as I know, in the limit of low energy i.e. $|p| \to 0$, this function $f$ goes to a constant, and this is called the correlation length. I wanted to know why this is so. I never found an explicit expression for $\delta_{l}$, so it is difficult for me to conclude it myself (since $\delta_{l}$ also depends on $p$).